# Unique Id without submission of form in ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form there are 5 fields where I want to automatic generate roll number in 5th field after filling up 4 fields(Name,Phone,Course,Batch) without submitting form.but after filling up 4 field no value comes in 5th field(roll).Below is my code

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" <head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    function my_validate_func() {
        if ($('#name').val() != "" && $('#phone').val() != "" &&
            $('#course').val() != "" && $('#center').val() != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'submit.php',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#roll').val(response.roll);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="course" id="course" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="center" id="center" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" value="<?php $roll; ?>">
    </form>
</body>

</html>

**submit.php code is below**

<?php
$roll=rand(100000,999999);
echo $roll;
?>
```

Comment: Why does the $roll value get displayed in the input before it is declared?  Do you want users to be able to manipulate it?  Would you rather use `<input type='hidden'>`?

Comment: i do it in hidden field, but still not generate

Comment: I fear this is going down a duplicate question path.  Be sure to echo your `$roll` into your html and continue searching SO, starting with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php  Please consider removing your question and only post after you have spent sufficient time trying to self solve.

Comment: remove `<?php $roll; ?>` and change `$('#roll').val(response.roll);` to `$('#roll').val(response);`, if the roll in php isn't saved anywhere you could generate random number in javascript as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Corrected Code,

<!DOCTYPE> 
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() {});
    function my_validate_func() {
        if ($('#name').val() != "" && $('#phone').val() != "" &&
            $('#course').val() != "" && $('#center').val() != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'submit.php',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#roll').val(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="course" id="course" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="center" id="center" onchange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" value="">
    </form>
</body>

</html>

**submit.php code is below**

<?php
$roll=rand(100000,999999);
echo $roll;
?>


** Updated submit.php code is below**

<?php
```

Function getUniqueRandomNo()
{
    $roll=rand(100000,999999);
    // Check in db, for example in emp_id field
$id = mysql_query("select emp_id from emp_master where emp_id = '$roll'");
If($id !=null)
{
return getUniqueRandomNo();
}
else{

Return $roll;
}
}
    echo getUniqueRandomNo();
    ?>
Note: I have written this recursive function code directly here, please do necessary update. There might be syntax error.

Comment: if i generate unique id through rand function like that ,is there any possibility to generate duplicate value?

Comment: Yes if database is big and function already created a big number of series there is chance of duplicacy. To remove this possibility append timestamp value. Timestamp value can never be repeatative. Have you got to resolve issue by my code? If yes Mark is positive so other can also get benefit if encounter with same problem. Thanks

Comment: suppose i want to insert rand function value in mysql database,then how can i check that this random generated value is already in our database or not  ?

Comment: Thanks Doni. If you ready to use timestamp then no need to check as it will never be duplicated. Else you need to write recursive function in place of that 2 line. Function​ will keep checking in db till you get unique no. Something like I have added in my answer now.

Comment: can you tell one things? suppose i want to insert rand function value in mysql database, how can i check through timestamp. actually i use simple query like INSERT INTO student (`roll`) values ($_POST['rand']); here how can i use timestamp for checking duplicating value exist or not.

Comment: can you answer this question? actually radio button does not work ,please check this link. if possible to answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357769/radio-button-validate-in-html5/44357912#44357912

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //You can use keyup or change or etc.
  $('input.fields').change(function() {
    var check_empty = $('input.fields').filter(function(item) {
        return $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0;
    }).length === 0;
    
    if(check_empty === true){
     //uncomment in rell test
     /*$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'submit.php',
        success: function(response) {
          $('#roll').val(response.roll);
        }
      });*/
      
      //for test
      $('#roll').val(Math.random());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="fields" >
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="fields">
  <input type="text" name="course" id="course" class="fields">
  <input type="text" name="center" id="center" class="fields">
  <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: this code generate multiple times... if he use ajax instead of js then lord have mercy with that server xD

Comment: @Kazz Ajax request send if 4th `fields` is not empty.