# rand function value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i create rand funtion for generating random value and concatenate with other value and show in the text field through ajax before insert this value. but here how can i check this random generating value is exists or not in database before inserting this value in database.if value is exists then again generate rand function value and again concatenate this. how can i do this? my code is below

```
<?php $rand=rand(100000,999999);
$roll=$branch_name.$name.$course.$year.$rand;
echo $roll;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that i should explain how its works, but its really a big amount of information about this in google...

In a link below i attached the url for it with some explain:

[How create a radio button in html5](http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/site-development/how-to-create-a-radio-button-in-an-html5-form/)

Comment: Could you update your post in full form with radio button on jsfidle or codepen?

Comment: First, i dont see there any form ;) 
form-group its not form, just class.
So you should add form there (<form></form). Also you should think about change the code and do some staff dynamicly. Its not really good idea for so many inputs/labels in plain html :) Just generate most of them in loop with data :) You will find that really quick.
When you add form and do some clean in code try validation again and write the output :)

Comment: <form> tag is also here see

Comment: Here I add <form> look carefully

Comment: You make really really a lot of error in code :/
And not only in form.
The src for script, some script in script (this shouldnt be like this).
You add some css in html (use the css file for this) 
And element must refer to a non-hidden form control..
And it should be good after fix it :) 
Ofcourse there will be some errors for HTML5 becouse you use php there :)